# Function for checking a number not returning correct result in C++?

Tags: c++, arrays, function, primes, cout

I have a function isPrime() that checks if a number if prime. On the first line the user enters an integer - the number of the tests. On the next lines  are the numbers; If the number is not prime, 0 is written into a dynamic array (vector). Else  - 1 goes to the array. However if I enter the following input:

```
3 
21
41
7
```

The program outputs:

```
1
1
1
```

But 21 is obviously not a prime number since it has divisors 7 and 3. My question is what am I doing wrong?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
vector <int> rez;
bool isPrime(int n)
{
    for(int i=2; i<sqrt(n); i++)
    {

        if(n%i!=0)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
int main()
{
    int k,num;
    cin>>k;
    for(int i=0; i<k; i++)
    {
        cin>>num;
        if(isPrime(num))
        {
            rez.push_back(1);
        }
        else
        {
            rez.push_back(0);
        }
    }

    for(int i=0; i<rez.size(); i++)
    {
        cout<<rez[i]<<endl;
    }

    cout<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The code you show us should not even build. Did you really copy-paste your actual code?

Comment: This might also be a good time to [learn how to debug your programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). Stepping through the code should make the problem *very* obvious to find.

Comment: `vector <int> rez;
a` ... what is `a`  ??

Comment: Your loop doesn't loop as it returns at first iteration anyway.

Answer (score 1):

```
if(n%i!=0)
{
    return true;
}
else
{
    return false;
}
```

This checks if the number is divisible by the first number in the loop, which is `2`, and then exits the function, since there is a return statement in either clause of the conditional. This means that the loop only runs for 1 iteration. In the first case, you enter 21. 21 IS NOT divisible by 2, so the function returns true. The same goes for the other numbers. Change your conditional to:

```
if (num % i == 0)
{ 
    return false;
}
```

This checks if the number is divisible by the current index you are checking, and if it IS divisible, it returns false. (Definition of prime numbers). You don't need an else statement, since you need to check if other numbers are possible factors of this number.

Answer (score 0):

You implement the function wrongly. The first `return` is wrong. You check only devising by 2 and your function exits with `true`. You should continue the loop and return `true` after loop only.

Additionally you could make your function faster twice if you check devising by 2 separately, then start the loop from 3 with increasing the index by 2.

Comment: To add to this, you can debug your program easily by testing your input.
The square root of 21 is 4,6.  As you can see, your program will test for 3 and return true, which is obviously wrong.